# Wicket 6 DefaultNestedTree not expanding on folder click

Tags: java, jboss, tree, wicket

I'm displaying some folders and files in a DefaultNestedTree using Wicket 6 but when clicking on a folder nothing happens... The folder should expand ofcourse.

I've build the three using this [example](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/tree/?0) page and [source](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/tree/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.source.SourcesPage?0&SourcesPage) from Wicket.

The code to be exact;

*HTML:*

```
<div id="treeClass">
    <span wicket:id="dirTree">directory tree</span>
</div>
```

*JAVA:*

```
tree = new DefaultNestedTree<Product>("dirTree", provider)
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected Component newContentComponent(String id, IModel<Product> node)
    {
        return super.newContentComponent(id, node);
    }
};
```

The tree gets filled correctly with folders (and subfolder/files) but when clicking on it it doesn't expand. MouseHover shows a clickable link, but could just be styling. In the example page at Wicket [1](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/tree/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.source.SourcesPage?0&SourcesPage) I'm not seeing anything to hanlde a click/expand though. And it works well there.

Using a button and AJAX i'm able to expand the tree via java code but after that when clicking on a folder/file I get an 'Access Denied' error page.

[image: Tree with content normal and expanded]

**What am I missing or doing wrong..?**

Comment: Put a breakpoint in org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.tree.content.Folder#onClick() and see what happens there.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! After deeper investigation I found that my Model was losing the right id to get the objects from my tree. The two folders displayed at the top thus contained no child(s). 
My button to expand all used the root of the tree and not the Models so the error wasn't triggered there.

Since I got your attention Sven, why doesn't this DefaultNestesTree use HTML list items (lu, li etc.) instead of the div's? I saw your nice (old)Wicket tree library output here: https://code.google.com/p/wicket-tree/wiki/MarkupFetishism

Comment: Nested HTML list items where problematic in IE-X (I can't remember the exact version).

Comment: Thanks! That's a legit answer, stupid IE.
Further comparision with the old Wicket1.6 tree shows me that the new DefaultNestedTree displays .zip files while the old tree didn't. Is there any easy way to disable this? Each of my folders contains a .zip for download, but I don't want it displayed in the tree.
I've tried overriding org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.tree.content.Folder#isVisible() but then the expanding/collapsing goes wrong..

Answer (score 1):

For future searchers, I was having a similar issue and it turned out that my node type did not have `equals()` and `hash()` implemented properly.  This was required because they were Hibernate entities that I was refreshing each request -- thus they were different objects and the Folder was not able to find which branch was selected with `equals()`.